# I can't delete space in my css file

Tags: css

I created in blog spot a new page for a gallery with a menu, the result is good but there is so much space between the buttons, and a big gap in the top of the page, when I try `<b>` or `<p>` It wont go, I also tried to minimise the space with another script but the result was no space but unclickable buttons, and always when I success deleting spaces, the buttons wont work ! Please help me ! (It works on dreamweaver perfectly but not on Blogger !
This is the code :

```
<p> <p><b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/></p>


<p><style type="text/css">
.menutitle{
cursor:pointer;
<span style="margin-bottom: 5px"><br>;
background-color:#000000 ;
color:#FFF;
width:140px;
padding:2px;
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;
/*/*/border:0px solid #000000;/* */
}</p>
.submenu{
margin-bottom: 0.5em;
} 
</style> </p>
</b:if>
 <p><script type="text/javascript">
var persistmenu="yes" //"yes" or "no". Make sure each SPAN content contains an incrementing ID starting at 1 (id="sub1", id="sub2", etc)
var persisttype="sitewide" //enter "sitewide" for menu to persist across site, "local" for this page only
if (document.getElementById){ //DynamicDrive.com change
document.write('<style type="text/css">\n')
document.write('.submenu{display: none;}\n')
document.write('</style>\n')
}
function SwitchMenu(obj){
    if(document.getElementById){
    var el = document.getElementById(obj);
    var ar = document.getElementById("masterdiv").getElementsByTagName("span"); //DynamicDrive.com change
        if(el.style.display != "block"){ //DynamicDrive.com change
            for (var i=0; i<ar.length; i++){
                if (ar[i].className=="submenu") //DynamicDrive.com change
                ar[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            el.style.display = "block";
        }else{
            el.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
function get_cookie(Name) { 
var search = Name + "="
var returnvalue = "";
if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search)
if (offset != -1) { 
offset += search.length
end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
returnvalue=unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end))
}
}
return returnvalue;
}

function onloadfunction(){
if (persistmenu=="yes"){
var cookiename=(persisttype=="sitewide")? "switchmenu" : window.location.pathname
var cookievalue=get_cookie(cookiename)
if (cookievalue!="")
document.getElementById(cookievalue).style.display="block"
}
}
function savemenustate(){
var inc=1, blockid=""
while (document.getElementById("sub"+inc)){
if (document.getElementById("sub"+inc).style.display=="block"){
blockid="sub"+inc
break
}
inc++
}
var cookiename=(persisttype=="sitewide")? "switchmenu" : window.location.pathname
var cookievalue=(persisttype=="sitewide")? blockid+";path=/" : blockid
document.cookie=cookiename+"="+cookievalue
}
<p>if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", onloadfunction, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", onloadfunction)
else if (document.getElementById)
window.onload=onloadfunction
if (persistmenu=="yes" && document.getElementById)
window.onunload=savemenustate </p>
</script></p>

<!-- Keep all menus within masterdiv-->
<div id="masterdiv">

   <div class="menutitle" onclick="SwitchMenu('sub1')">Dior</div>
    <span class="submenu" id="sub1">
 <p><div id="PictoBrowser110620155241">Get the flash player here: http://www.adobe.com/flashplayer</div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.db798.com/pictobrowser/swfobject.js"></script><script type="text/javascript"> var so = new SWFObject("http://www.db798.com/pictobrowser.swf", "PictoBrowser", "500", "650", "8", "#000000"); so.addVariable("source", "sets"); so.addVariable("names", "Scheisse"); so.addVariable("userName", "ScheisseMag"); so.addVariable("userId", "64286522@N04"); so.addVariable("ids", "72157626880953125"); so.addVariable("titles", "on"); so.addVariable("displayNotes", "on"); so.addVariable("thumbAutoHide", "off"); so.addVariable("imageSize", "medium"); so.addVariable("vAlign", "mid"); so.addVariable("vertOffset", "0"); so.addVariable("colorHexVar", "f"); so.addVariable("initialScale", "on"); so.addVariable("bgAlpha", "8"); so.write("PictoBrowser110620155241");    </script>
</span>
 <div class="menutitle" onclick="SwitchMenu('sub2')">FAQ/Help</div>
    <span class="submenu" id="sub2">
        - <a href="notice.htm">Usage Terms</a><br>
        - <a href="faqs.htm">DHTML FAQs</a><br>
        - <a href="help.htm">Scripts FAQs</a></span>
 <div class="menutitle" onclick="SwitchMenu('sub3')">Help Forum</div>
    <span class="submenu" id="sub3">
        - <a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a><br></span>
    <div class="menutitle" onclick="SwitchMenu('sub4')">Cool Links</div>
    <span class="submenu" id="sub4">
        - <a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a><br>
        - <a href="http://www.freewarejava.com">Freewarejava</a><br>
        - <a href="http://www.cooltext.com">Cool Text</a><br>
        - <a href="http://www.google.com">Google.com</a>
    </span></p></div> </p>
```

Comment: who voted up for this question, lol ?

Comment: Seems to work ok... http://jsfiddle.net/3hZCA/

Comment: I'm not sure that it will help, but do you have a live page showing the problem that you can share a link to?

Comment: @thirtydot http://scheissemag.blogspot.com/p/ny-women.html

Comment: I see it, but I'm not sure what the problem is. A screenshot with arrows or circles around the problem area(s) would help.

Comment: @thirtydot the problem is the space between eich bouton like between Dior and Faq/help and help forum, they are meant to be attached to each other, also the gap between the Title of the page and those menus ! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Firefox, because it doesn't seem to work the same using other browsers..

> the problem is the space between eich
>   bouton like between Dior and Faq/help
>   and help forum, they are meant to be
>   attached to each other

I'll start by saying that I'm not familiar with Blogger.

Your HTML:

```
<div class="menutitle" onclick="SwitchMenu('sub2')">FAQ/Help</div>
<span class="submenu" id="sub2">..</span>
<div class="menutitle" onclick="SwitchMenu('sub3')">
```

What you get if you View Source on your page:

```
<div class="menutitle" onclick="SwitchMenu('sub2')">FAQ/Help</div>
<span class="submenu" id="sub2">..</span><br />   <!-- extra br! -->
<div class="menutitle" onclick="SwitchMenu('sub3')">
```

**Those frequent extra `<br />`s are the main problem. There are lots of them.** You need to prevent them from being inserted. Perhaps removing the whitespace in *your HTML* will help? Like this:

```
<div class="menutitle" onclick="SwitchMenu('sub2')">FAQ/Help</div>
<span class="submenu" id="sub2">..</span><div class="menutitle" onclick="SwitchMenu('sub3')">
```

> also the gap between the Title of the
>   page and those menus !

You need to get rid of many instances of `<p>` and `</p>` that are wrapped around everything, including `<script>`s, for some reason..

Also, you have the same problem with `<br />`s being magically inserted. Again, compare *your HTML* to what comes out when you use View Source in your browser.

After removing those extraneous `<p>` and `</p>` and `<br />` [using Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (just to test), this was the result:

[image]